# Is it possible to have a different BigQuery quota for different users within the same project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

Is it possible to have a different BigQuery quota for different users within the same project?

I know that I can set a limit on the 'Query usage per day per user' for a given project via the IAM and admin section of GCP (following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas)).

I'd like to know if it were possible to have a different per user limit. i.e. say set a limit of 2 TB per day for John but only 1 TB per day for Jane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am working for Google Cloud and a coworker opened on November 15 a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119608422) to do what you need.

There is actually a workaround for this, which would consist on creating a different project for each user you want to grant the custom quota. Depending on the amount of different users you want to do this for it will maybe not be that feasible.

Comment: Thanks for this - I suspected it was impossible (I already thought of the separate project workaround) but good to get confirmation. I'll keep an eye on the Feature Request.