# Create exception for "BigQuery query usage per day per user" quota limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, quota

I set a daily restriction of 4TB for `Query use per day per user` in my GCP project. This is ideal because it stops developers from accidentally consuming excessive amounts of data or from querying tables without using partitioning filters.

Nevertheless, I would prefer for this limit not to apply to a service account that is running a dbt process in the background. Furthermore, this regulation shouldn't apply to some other Data Engineers either.

Is there any role or permission I can grant to these users and service accounts to have unlimited query usage? The behavior I want is that by default the limit is applied, unless a member has this specific role.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a different BigQuery quota for different users within the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419209/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-bigquery-quota-for-different-users-within-the)

Comment: @AleixCC Somehow, but I don't need to have different quotas for different users. What I am looking for is a specific role (or something) I can assign to a member so that the project quota doesn't apply to it

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738181/google-bigquery-custom-quota-for-each-user) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew Thanks for the link, but I feel like that's quite an over-engineered solution to my needs. Moreover, as the response suggests, it may take some time to receive the data on the BQ table, so costly queries could be run meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas), `it is not possible to assign a custom quota to a specific user or service account`. When you apply a quota limitation, the user or service account comes under this quota. Based on my understanding, **the quota limit does not consider roles of service accounts**.**Custom quotas are applied to all users and service accounts within a project**.

For your requirement as I mentioned in the comment  you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738181/google-bigquery-custom-quota-for-each-user). But For this workaround, you need to use other GCP products such as Google Cloud.

You can consider the following example as a workaround for your requirement:

The quota limits can be assigned to different projects, and the users can be assigned to their respective projects:

For example,

You can create `projects 1` and `project 2` and grant all the necessary permissions so that users and accounts in each project can query the dataset in the `main project`. Then assign the different  quota limits  to `project 1` and  `project 2`. Now  assign the `user1`(users and service accounts have quota limitation)  to `project 1` and  `user2`(users and service accounts has no limitation or little limitation) to `project 2`.

As @AleixCC  mentioned there is an almost similar [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119608422) that already exists and you can track the progress. However, you can open another [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.